# Change the Value of radio buttons with other radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been trying to create a dynamic form that changes the value of the offered packages, by choosing what type of customer the user is.
My JSFiddle of the section of the form:

https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/ch8z0hry/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#student').on('click', function() {
    $('#minimal').val('100');
    $('#soundonly').val('150');
    $('#soundandlight').val('175');
    $('#totalpartypackage').val('200');
});
$('#private').on('click', function() {
    $('#minimal').val('150');
    $('#soundonly').val('200');
    $('#soundandlight').val('300');
    $('#totalpartypackage').val('400');
});
$('#company').on('click', function() {
    $('#minimal').val('200');
    $('#soundonly').val('300');
    $('#soundandlight').val('400');
    $('#totalpartypackage').val('50');
});
});
```

I searched the internet for hours trying different solutions. In the end I read through the W3schools page about JQuery event methods and tried to piece together what seemed right to me. In the JSFiddle I also included a script to check if the values of the Radiobuttons. I noticed that the JSFiddle seems to work but on my own private server it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am currently running the page on my synology NAS with Webstation.

Comment: So the above snippet does work, right? Can you please open the developer console in your browser and share with us the output when you run this code on your server?

Comment: I am not completely sure if I get it, but in Safari the Javascript console doesn't output anything when I run the code. There are no errors what so ever. I will give the site a try on another server to see if it's the server software.

Comment: I Uploaded it to the other server and I stil get the same result.

Comment: I realized that there was an error of duplicate ID's on the Page. I fixed that but function still won't work.

Comment: I worked all night trying to figure it out. Turns out there weres some errors in the rest of my page that caused the function to fail. In the end the code works perfectly with one minor problem. When the page first loads, the values are blank. The user has to click on a radio button to insert the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have error javascript in console? And you have included jquery?

Try insert this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added these in the external resources

Comment: you must add these 3 includes in the <head>..
What's in your <head>?

Comment: I have been using Jquerymobile successfully for quite some time now, (since version 1.1). I include the most recent Jquery, Jquerymobile and Jquery css every time. But Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have been Fiddling around with the code and came to the conclusion that it actually works fine. You can go check out my JSFiddle to see the final result:

https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/no0qfqhh/

The code I started with was actually already correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#student').on('click', function() {
    $('#minimal').val('100');
    $('#soundonly').val('150');
    $('#soundandlight').val('175');
    $('#totalpartypackage').val('200');
});
$('#private').on('click', function() {
    $('#minimal').val('150');
    $('#soundonly').val('200');
    $('#soundandlight').val('300');
    $('#totalpartypackage').val('400');
});
$('#company').on('click', function() {
    $('#minimal').val('200');
    $('#soundonly').val('300');
    $('#soundandlight').val('400');
    $('#totalpartypackage').val('50');
});
});
```

Using the button at the end made checking the code very simple, especially for future testing when it comes to adding more values and displaying them in the end.

```
<div class="form-field-contain" id="customertype">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="customertype" id="student" value="Student/Apprentice">Stundent/Apprentice</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="customertype" id="private" value="private" checked="checked">Private</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="customertype" id="company" value="company">Company</label>
                    </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field-contain" id="prices">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="pricetag">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="price" id="minimal" value checked="checked">Minimal</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="price" id="soundonly" value>Sound Only</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="price" id="soundandlight" value>Sound and Light</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="price" id="totalpartypackage" value>Total Party Package</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="price" id="custom" value="">Custom</label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
    <script>
                function display() {
                    var a = document.getElementById('minimal').value;
                    var b = document.getElementById('soundonly').value;
                    var c = document.getElementById('soundandlight').value;
                    var d = document.getElementById('totalpartypackage').value;
                            alert("The value of the radio buttons are: " + a + " and " + b + " and " + c + " and " + d);
        }
                </script>
            <button onclick="display()">Check</button>
```

Thank to everyone that contributed in any way.